# Periodic Istio Citadel pod restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, grpc, istio, istio-operator

`Istio-citadel` pods of `istio 1.4.10 helm` release, are restarted periodically.

2 replicas of `istio-citadel` are running.

This happens once in every 4-5 days, when the number of CSR requests reaches 28.3k and memory reaches 9.8G. Memory increases steadily after the restart until it crashes again. CPU spike is also observed consuming around 10 CPU.

Could see the below error log 4 mins before the restart.

```
Sep 27, 2021 @ 12:20:39.3702021-09-27T06:50:39.370213Z  error   ca.liveness turns unavailable: 1 error occurred:
Sep 27, 2021 @ 12:20:39.370 * liveness: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp <citadel-service-ip>:8060: connect: cannot assign requested address"
```

Want to understand the error message and the reason that could explain periodic restart.

Comment: Just to calrify - you are using Istio 1.4.10?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: That's quite old version, latest version is 1.11. You may want to upgrade. Please include istio-citadel pods manifests in your question.

Answer (score 1):

@p10l is right: `citadel` was replaced by `Istio CA`

There is a commit more than year ago:  [replace Citadel with Istio CA by istio-testing · Pull Request #6825 · istio/istio.io](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/6825)

Also, there are commits in documentation:

- [Remove citadel reference by jacob-delgado · Pull Request #9624 · istio/istio.io](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/9624)
- [Remove citadel from installation instructions by myidpt · Pull Request #7872 · istio/istio.io](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/7872)
- [Best-Practices: Remove reference to Citadel. by justinpettit · Pull Request #7398 · istio/istio.io](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/7398)

So, i'd suggest to update your `istio`